# What is GetAsyncKeyState's return value?

Tags: ruby, winapi

I trying to use `GetAsyncKeyState` in a project I'm working on. The only problem is I don't know what value it returns, and in turn how to check for it. According to the MSN [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate):

> Type: SHORT
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key was pressed since the last call to **GetAsyncKeyState**, and whether the key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to **GetAsyncKeyState**. However, you should not rely on this last behavior; for more information, see the Remarks.

I know that type `SHORT` is a number, but I've seen a lot of different answers across StackOverflow, and the internet, but what is GetAsyncKeyState's return value when it evaluates to true, does it return 0 or 0x8001?

Comment: It returns a set of flags, encoded into a single 16-bit value. The documentation explains, what the individual flags are and where they are stored. What's the specific problem you have?

Comment: The canonical way to test if the last bit is set is to test `<0`

Comment: @IInspectable The problem is what value is returned when a key is pressed? Does it return that key's hex value or another number? I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If the last bit is set will it be one?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. It returns different values, when the respective key is pressed, but it will always return values, where the most significant bit is set.

Comment: @Practical I don't understand that question. A bit can be 0 or 1. When bit is set the bit's value is 1. When the last bit is set the number must be negative. All negative numbers have the last bit set. Hence my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return value can be one of 4 possible values:

- 0x0000
- 0x0001
- 0x8000
- 0x8001

Use `& 0x8000` (or alternatively `< 0` since `SHORT` is a signed type) to check if "the most significant bit is set" (which makes a signed type negative).

Use `& 0x0001` to check if "the least significant bit is set".

Comment: The less-than-zero check only works in case `1` a programming language provides support for integer values of a specific size, `2` all bits are used to represent the value in those types, and `3` the programming language uses two's complement to represent signed values. Ruby doesn't appear to be a programming language that provides support for all of the aforementioned.